# How can we add dynamic data into our SMS messages that is send via the API

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, sms, dynamic-content

We want to send SMS messages via the API (/sms/v1/messageContact/XXXXXX/send). The SMS messages contain dynamic data like timestamps. So for example we have the following message:

'We will arrive between TIME1 and TIME2'

TIME1 and TIME2 are variables. How can we achieve this with the API? Is something like this possible? (beneath is just an example what to achieve):

```
{
    "mobileNumbers": [
    "31612345678"
    ],
    "Subscribe": true,
    "Resubscribe": true,
    "keyword": "TRANSACTIONAL",
    "Override": true,
    "time1": "9/20/2021 14:00:00",
     "time2": "10/21/2021 16:00:00",
    "messageText": "We will arrive between %%=v(@time1)=%% and %%=v(@time2)=%%"
    
}
```

Comment: why don't you just put the time value in the message text?

Comment: The "problem" is that we want to store the SMS messages with content in the Marketing Cloud. Because we have dynamic data, it is, as far is I know, not possible because there is no data extension where we can retrieve the data from. The system from which we receive the data has some difficulties putting everything allready within the messageText.